# Taking new line as a input in java

Tags: java, while-loop, char, ascii, indexoutofboundsexception

I want to if the input is a new line, then it will randomize character in the alphabet.
Here is my code :

```
while(!((specialChar >= 65 && specialChar <= 90) || (specialChar >= 97 && specialChar <= 122))) {
        System.out.print("Apa karakter spesial untuk hari ini? (Kosongkan untuk menggunakan karakter acak): ");
        specialChar = sc.nextLine().charAt(0);
        
        if(specialChar >= 65 && specialChar <= 90 || specialChar >= 97 && specialChar <= 122) {
          System.out.println("Karakter spesial hari ini adalah " + specialChar);
          break;
        }
        else if(specialChar == 10) {
          char c = (char)(randomizer.nextInt(26) + 'A');
          System.out.println("Karakter spesial hari ini adalah " + specialChar);
        }
        System.out.println("Karakter harus merupakan alfabet!");
      }
```

But it resulting as indexoutofbounds:0. If I use .next() then it will not read the new line, right? I'm so confused.

Answer (score 0):

This: `sc.nextLine().charAt(0);` will fail with that exact exception if `sc.nextLine()` returns an empty string.

The reason is a bit of an unfortunate thing with scanner. Don't use nextLine, ever - scanners fail if you mix nextLine with any other next method, and I assume someplace you're e.g. calling `.nextInt()` or some such, and thus your scanner's in a messed up state*.

Instead, if your intent is to read input until an enter is pressed (Vs. the default behaviour, which is to read until whitespace), just tell the scanner that you want newlines to be the delimiter:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(...);
s.useDelimiter("\r?\n");
```

Then, to read a string, use `next()`, to read a number, use `nextInt()`, etcetera.

*) To any commenters or would be voters who think 'hey, just call nextLine() once and toss the result to expunge the newline - no, that does not work if the input is space delimited. Whereas updating the delimiter and using `.next()` to read lines has no such caveats.